# upload/change avatar photo using html5 / javascript and php?

Tags: php, javascript

i was looking at this link that allows a user to drag an image over an avatar/profile photo and they can drop the image over it which will change/upload a different image.

link: http://css-tricks.com/html5-drag-and-drop-avatar-changer-with-resizing-and-cropping/

what i was wondering now is how i could use php to upload the photo, would anyone please be able to show me how i can do this? thanks

html:

```
<title>Drag Avatar</title>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
```

```
<div class="page-wrap">

    <h1>Drag & Drop Image to Change Avatar</h1>

    <div class="profile">

        <div class="profile-avatar-wrap">
            <img src="images/256.jpg" id="profile-avatar" alt="Image for Profile">
        </div>

        <h2>Betty Miller</h2>
        <div class="location">Palo Alto, CA</div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur voluptatem accusantium voluptas doloremque porro temporibus aut rerum possimus cum minus.</p>

    </div>

    <h3>You could do this with a file input too...</h3>
    <input type="file" id="uploader">

</div>

<!-- In real life, these scripts are combined -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="resample.js"></script>
<script src="avatar.js"></script>
```

resample.js:

```
var Resample = (function (canvas) {

 // (C) WebReflection Mit Style License

 function Resample(img, width, height, onresample) {
  var

   load = typeof img == "string",
   i = load || img;

  // if string, a new Image is needed
  if (load) {
   i = new Image;
   i.onload = onload;
   i.onerror = onerror;
  }

  i._onresample = onresample;
  i._width = width;
  i._height = height;
  load ? (i.src = img) : onload.call(img);
 }

 function onerror() {
  throw ("not found: " + this.src);
 }

 function onload() {
  var
   img = this,
   width = img._width,
   height = img._height,
   onresample = img._onresample
  ;
  // if width and height are both specified
  // the resample uses these pixels
  // if width is specified but not the height
  // the resample respects proportions
  // accordingly with orginal size
  // same is if there is a height, but no width
  var minValue = Math.min(img.height, img.width);
  width == null && (width = round(img.width * height / img.height));
  height == null && (height = round(img.height * width / img.width));

  delete img._onresample;
  delete img._width;
  delete img._height;

  // when we reassign a canvas size
  // this clears automatically
  // the size should be exactly the same
  // of the final image
  // so that toDataURL ctx method
  // will return the whole canvas as png
  // without empty spaces or lines
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  // drawImage has different overloads
  // in this case we need the following one ...
  context.drawImage(
   // original image
   img,
   // starting x point
   0,
   // starting y point
   0,
   // image width
   minValue,
   // image height
   minValue,
   // destination x point
   0,
   // destination y point
   0,
   // destination width
   width,
   // destination height
   height
  );
  // retrieve the canvas content as
  // base4 encoded PNG image
  // and pass the result to the callback
  onresample(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
 }

 var context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  // local scope shortcut
  round = Math.round
 ;

 return Resample;

}(
 this.document.createElement("canvas"))
);
```

avatar.js:

```
// Required for drag and drop file access
jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');

// IIFE to prevent globals
(function() {

  var s;
  var Avatar = {

    settings: {
      bod: $("body"),
      img: $("#profile-avatar"),
      fileInput: $("#uploader")
    },

    init: function() {
      s = Avatar.settings;
      Avatar.bindUIActions();
    },

    bindUIActions: function() {

      var timer;

      s.bod.on("dragover", function(event) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        if (event.currentTarget == s.bod[0]) {
          Avatar.showDroppableArea();
        }

        // Required for drop to work
        return false;
      });

      s.bod.on('dragleave', function(event) {
        if (event.currentTarget == s.bod[0]) {
          // Flicker protection
          timer = setTimeout(function() {
            Avatar.hideDroppableArea();
          }, 200);
        }
      });

      s.bod.on('drop', function(event) {
        // Or else the browser will open the file
        event.preventDefault();

        Avatar.handleDrop(event.dataTransfer.files);
      });

      s.fileInput.on('change', function(event) {
        Avatar.handleDrop(event.target.files);
      });
    },

    showDroppableArea: function() {
      s.bod.addClass("droppable");
    },

    hideDroppableArea: function() {
      s.bod.removeClass("droppable");
    },

    handleDrop: function(files) {

      Avatar.hideDroppableArea();

      // Multiple files can be dropped. Lets only deal with the "first" one.
      var file = files[0];

      if (typeof file !== 'undefined' && file.type.match('image.*')) {

        Avatar.resizeImage(file, 256, function(data) {
          Avatar.placeImage(data);
        });

      } else {

        alert("That file wasn't an image.");

      }

    },

    resizeImage: function(file, size, callback) {

      var fileTracker = new FileReader;
      fileTracker.onload = function() {
        Resample(
         this.result,
         size,
         size,
         callback
       );
      }
      fileTracker.readAsDataURL(file);

      fileTracker.onabort = function() {
        alert("The upload was aborted.");
      }
      fileTracker.onerror = function() {
        alert("An error occured while reading the file.");
      }

    },

    placeImage: function(data) {
      s.img.attr("src", data);
    }

  }

  Avatar.init();

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_file_upload.htm#step-heading

Create a form like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
Please choose a file: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

And the php would be something like this:

```
$target = "upload/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ;
$ok=1;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)){
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
}
else{
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
```

for more options (limit file size, extension, etc) check the link

Comment: Link only answers should include a summary of the content

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know. I edited it and I guess it's okay now?